# Componentdidmount not called when back button on browser is called- ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Lets say I’m on a page and when i click it navigates me to a component using props.history. Now suppose the page where i am routed to is a functional component and when i press back button on the browser the previous page’s componentdidmount is not called whereas if the page im navigated to is a class component and when i hit the back button the previous page’s componentdidmount is called.

Code:

In Home.js(class component) renders this : `<Navbar obj={this.state}></Navbar>`

In Navbar.js(Functional component) I have the following which redirects me to the new component Userinfo. In which when i click back the whole issue starts. If the userinfo is a class component componentdidmount works, and if userinfo is a functional component the componentdidmount does not get triggered. componentdidmount of Home.js basically.

```
<Link
  style={{ color: "white" }}
  to={{ pathname: "/Userinfo", search: "?" + props.obj.key }}
>
  {props.obj.Name}
</Link>
```

I want to know the reason behind this behaviour. Thanks

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understood your problem correctly. Have you added a method named `componentDidMount` to a function component? In this case it's obvious because function components don't have the same lifecycle functions. In this case you have to use `useEffect(()=>{<your componendDidMount code here>},[])` to simulate didmount and didunmount

Comment: No. componentdidmount is not getting triggered when back button is clicked. componentdidmount that I am talking about is in Home.js which is a class component.

Comment: Can you post your code for functional component?

Comment: See let me explain.  There is home.js(class component) then there is navbar.js(functional component) which is called inside home.js. Then the navbar.js has <Link> which navigates me to another functional component from where when I hit back the class component(home.js) doesn't trigger componentdidmount.

Comment: Functional component is like this : const test=(props)=>{console.log("testing") return(<div></div>)}……..then it is exported like normally.